# AbpApplicationConfigurationController error executing GetAsync()

Tags: .net-7.0, .net-8.0, abp.io

I have upgraded my abp.io .net application from abp.io version 7.3.2 to 7.4.2
I have also upgraded same application from .NET 7 to .NET 8
I have also updated the front-end angular packages to 7.4.2 for abp.io
I am having angular 17 running

While running the .net application its throwing below error :

```
[17:58:39 INF] Executing endpoint 'Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationConfigurations.AbpApplicationConfigurationController.GetAsync (Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc)'
[17:58:39 INF] Route matched with {area = "abp", action = "Get", controller = "AbpApplicationConfiguration", page = ""}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationConfigurations.ApplicationConfigurationDto] GetAsync(Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationConfigurations.ApplicationConfigurationRequestOptions) on controller Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationConfigurations.AbpApplicationConfigurationController (Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc).
[17:58:39 DBG] Executing AbpApplicationConfigurationAppService.GetAsync()...
[17:58:39 ERR] ---------- RemoteServiceErrorInfo ----------
{
  "code": null,
  "message": "An internal error occurred during your request!",
  "details": null,
  "data": {},
  "validationErrors": null
}

[17:58:39 ERR] Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationPolicy]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationPolicy]'.
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationPolicy]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationPolicy]'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationOptionsExtensions.GetPoliciesNames(AuthorizationOptions options)
   at Volo.Abp.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationPolicyProvider.GetPoliciesNamesAsync()
   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationConfigurations.AbpApplicationConfigurationAppService.GetAuthConfigAsync()
   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationConfigurations.AbpApplicationConfigurationAppService.GetAsync(ApplicationConfigurationRequestOptions options)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
   at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue`1.ProceedAsync()
   at Volo.Abp.GlobalFeatures.GlobalFeatureInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
   at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
   at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue`1.ProceedAsync()
   at Volo.Abp.Auditing.AuditingInterceptor.ProceedByLoggingAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation, AbpAuditingOptions options, IAuditingHelper auditingHelper, IAuditLogScope auditLogScope)
   at Volo.Abp.Auditing.AuditingInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
   at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
   at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue`1.ProceedAsync()
   at Volo.Abp.Validation.ValidationInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
   at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
   at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue`1.ProceedAsync()
   at Volo.Abp.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
   at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed)
   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationConfigurations.AbpApplicationConfigurationController.GetAsync(ApplicationConfigurationRequestOptions options)
   at lambda_method3300(Closure, Object)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|26_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
[17:58:39 INF] Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Volo.Abp.Http.RemoteServiceErrorResponse'.
[17:58:39 INF] Executed action Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationConfigurations.AbpApplicationConfigurationController.GetAsync (Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc) in 132.9365ms
[17:58:39 INF] Executed endpoint 'Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationConfigurations.AbpApplicationConfigurationController.GetAsync (Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc)'
[17:58:39 DBG] Added 0 entity changes to the current audit log
[17:58:40 DBG] Added 0 entity changes to the current audit log
[17:58:40 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44326/api/abp/application-configuration?includeLocalizationResources=false - 500 null application/json; charset=utf-8 354.9433ms
```

Please give the solution for the above error thanks.

I have tried changes mention in the below link, it is the migration module for abp.io from 7.3 to 7.4

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/7.4/Migration-Guides/Abp-7_4?_ga=2.141882615.45775511.1700467408-817650998.1673245649